# Why are they called the dihedral groups?

Tags: group-theory

Dihedron, two faced solid. It refers to the intersection of two planes. In what way are intersecting planes involved in these groups?

Answer (score 7):

The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedron) on this topic pretty much addresses this.

The polygon under examination has a "front" and a "back" which you can think of as being two different colors. They are basically two polygons back-to-back sharing edges and vertices. With vertices labeled by numbers, this allows you to see where vertices moved and if a flip occurred or not.

The linked page mentions thinking of this as a "degenerate prism" which has polygon ends, but no height, so that the two ends are back-to-back.

I can't find any reference to the "intersection of two planes" description. I can only guess it is an unclear explanation of this back-to-back description.

Comment: Not the picture I have in mind: two half-planes joined along a line. I don't see the dihedral group arising from this pic!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hmm, yes that pic does suggest the situation might be more complicated. Maybe "dihedron" in this sense is not meant to coincide with dihedral groups. It's clear why you would call that a dihedron (only two sides) but in this sense it is not really "closed". Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

It's the group of linear transformations generated by the reflections with respect to the two planes. The group will be finite if and only if the angle between the planes is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Here's a link to [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieder) for a change. If you don't speak German, don't worry. This is the picture I had in mind. Markedly different from the one in rschwieb's link!?

Comment: In other words, the two planes are the two mirrors generating the beautiful images in a kaleidoscope.

Comment: It seems D_2 cannot be generated this way. It would occur when the two planes were parallel, but then they would intersect, leaving a single reflection, only generating D_1. The reflections do generate D_n, n>=3. How does D_2 form?

Comment: @user2172001: You get a group of order 4, if you reflect w.r.t. two perpendicular planes. I would call that group the Klein four group ($V_4$) as opposed to $D_2$, though. What is $D_2$ for you? Note: the reflections with respect to two parallel, non-intersecting planes generate an infinite group of affine isometries, aka $D_\infty$.

Comment: < I meant parallel intersecting.

Comment: Yes D_2=V_4. I don't agree with you though. Two perpendicular planes generate rotations of pi/2, as well as two reflections (only one of which we need to count), giving us the D_4 group. What do you think D_4 is then?

Comment: For me $D_4$ is the symmetries of the square. Generated by reflections w.r.t. two planes forming angle $\pi/4$. For me the group $D_n$ has $2n$ elements, some authors disagree. Two perpendicular planes don't generate rotation by $\pi/2$. Remember that if the angle between two planes is $\theta$, the composition of the two reflections is rotation by $2\theta$ (not $\theta$)!

Comment: dahh. I'd been using a formula where phi represented phi/2. Thanks Jykri.